# Spring's @Transactional on class level applies to what methods?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, transactional

I have a class with several methods. Some are public and others aren't. See example below.

**What methods will be executed in a transaction context?** Only the public ones?

I couldn't find the answer in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-declarative-annotations).

```
@Transactionl
public class A {
  public void pub() {...}
  void pack() {...}
  protected void prot() {...}
  private void pri() {...}
}
```

Comment: Typically you have service interface and get the transaction functionality implemented via JDK proxies. In that case only the methods from service interface are proxied (and therefore transactional). Without service interface - your case, I guess, class A has no implements - you will have to go with proxy-target-class set to true and I would expect every method which you manage to call from outside the instance to be transactioned, i.e. public, protected and package default.

Comment: [It's in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-understanding-aop-proxies), just not in the section on `@Transactional`.  As Michal mentioned, `@Transactional` works by creating proxies.  So only calls that go in through the proxy will trigger the  `@Transactional` logic.  There are exceptions to this.  You could use compile time weaving instead of runtime proxies to get `@Transactional` on private/protected methods.

Comment: Well, I was wrong with my expectation. Actually the docs says it with wording pretty close to the answer of Paulius Matulionis. Searching in the  docs for 'If you do annotate protected, private or' finds it in the docs. I think his is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, only public methods will exhibit the transactional settings. If you put `@Transactional` annotation on private, protected or package-visible methods or on the class which has such methods, there won't be any error raised, it's just that your transactional settings won't be executed for those methods.

So in your case the transaction will be opened only on this method:

```
public void pub() {...}
```

The documentation could be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).

Comment: Thanks. How did you figure it out? Can you point to the source code or documentation?

Comment: Sorry. No mention of only public methods being transactional when the annotation is at the class level. What the docs do say is that the @Transactional annotation cannot be placed on **non-public** methods.

Comment: Anyhow, non-public must always be executed from a public method, so if the @Transactional annotation is defined on the class then all methods will be executed within a transaction context.

Comment: If I put `@Transactional` annotation on class level does it apply to public constructor of this class?